# How to display the background color of a cube and also the colors of two textures in OpenGL

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm trying to add two textures to a 3d cube. I achieved my goal, but on the way I lost the background color.

I want to show the original color of the images and also the background color. I use a mix, but it displays the background completely dark.

This is how it looks my fragmentShaderCode:

```
private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
                "uniform sampler2D u_Texture0;" +
                "uniform sampler2D u_Texture1;" +
                "uniform vec4 aColor;" +
                "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate0;" +
                "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate1;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "   vec4 base = texture2D(u_Texture0, v_TexCoordinate0);" +
                "   vec4 overlay = texture2D(u_Texture1, v_TexCoordinate1);" +
                "   mediump float ra = (overlay.a) * overlay.r + (1.0 - overlay.a) * base.r;" +
                "   mediump float ga = (overlay.a) * overlay.g + (1.0 - overlay.a) * base.g;" +
                "   mediump float ba = (overlay.a) * overlay.b + (1.0 - overlay.a) * base.b;" +
                "   gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(aColor.rgb, vec4(ra, ga, ba, 1.0).rgb , vec4(ra, ga, ba, 1.0).a), 1.0);" +
                "}";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alpha channel of `vec4(ra, ga, ba, 1.0)` is *1.0*. Therefore the result of `vec4(ra, ga, ba, 1.0).a` is always *1.0*.

You need to use the texture's alpha channels. e.g.: `max(base.a, overlay.a)`:

```c
vec3 textureColor = vec3(ra, ga, ba);
float textureAlpha = max(base.a, overlay.a);
gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(aColor.rgb, textureColor, textureAlpha), 1.0);
```

---

Simplify the code by mixing the texture colors with the [`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml) function:

```c
void main() {
    vec4 base = texture2D(u_Texture0, v_TexCoordinate0);
    vec4 overlay = texture2D(u_Texture1, v_TexCoordinate1);
    vec3 textureColor = mix(base.rgb, overlay.rgb, overlay.a);
    float textureAlpha = max(base.a, overlay.a);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(aColor.rgb, textureColor, textureAlpha), 1.0); 
}
```

Comment: wow, thanks! Is what I wanted!!

Comment: @Bocho Thank you. You're welcome.